# how exactly do you make 32bit versions of electron apps

Tags: node.js, electron

So I know this seems like a super basic and simple question but I'm unsure what the right answer is. Since in some cases I'm getting a bunch of contradictory answers.
Here is one that says just simple run

```
electron-forge make --arch=ia32
```

which gives me the following error, I have on idea what the work around would be - this is the standard compile spot for node globals:

```
An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
An error occured while making for target: squirrel
Failed with exit code: 1
Output:
Attempting to build package from 'controller.nuspec'.
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Error: Failed with exit code: 1
Output:
Attempting to build package from 'controller.nuspec'.
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\range\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\electron-winstaller\lib\spawn-promise.js:62:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
```

I finally got the thing working and now ma greeted with this error:
[image: Error]

But I have it installed here (my package.json)

```
{
    "name": "controller",
    "productName": "controller",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "My Electron application description",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron-forge start",
        "package": "electron-forge package",
        "make": "electron-forge make",
        "publish": "electron-forge publish",
        "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": {
        "name": "----------",
        "email": "------------"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "config": {
        "forge": {
            "packagerConfig": {},
            "makers": [{
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "controller"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
                    "platforms": [
                        "darwin"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
                    "config": {}
                },
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
                    "config": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
        "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
        "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
        "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
        "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
        "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0"
    }
}
```

also I tried installing compiler etc - that gives me this error

```
Electron forge was terminated:
You must depend on an EXACT version of "electron-prebuilt-compile" not a range (got "^8.2.0")
```

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/171

The next one I tried was from this thread:
https://github.com/HospitalRun/hospitalrun-frontend/issues/1074 , which told me:

```
npm ERR! missing script: electron:build
```

despite electron being npm installed

Whats happening here?

Comment: I don't use forge, so maybe this won't help you, but I use [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager)'s `arch` configuration.

Comment: I'm more like a fan of `electron-packager`. With it you generate 32-bit apps without a problem. But if you use non native modules, binaries are not good and you keep getting 'Module not found' error.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer/issues/219#issuecomment-417348086), the project is nested in too many folders.
Try moving the project to the root of your machine then create the build from there.

[Here's a resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) on why this is limited on Windows